# Test if the current thread is the main thread in javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, saxon

In javascript, I want to execute an action if the current thread is already a non-main thread, or pass it off to a non-main thread if the current thread is the main.

To this end, how can I test if the current thread is the main thread or a non-main thread?

If I call the jquery method `$.get()` the OnSuccess event is run on the non-main thread. I can achieve the pass-off simply by invoking `$.get()` on a do-nothing URL.

Why do I need to do this? There are some javascript calls that cause an ugly warning if called on the main thread. I would like to avoid this warning. The warning is ...

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

### What I have tried so far

```
function doOnNonMainThread( action) {
  if (thisIsANonMainThread()) {
      $.get( 'some-url', action, 'xml');
    } else {
      action();
    }
  }
```

### Update 1

I am invoking the Saxon-JS library (XPath evaluate function). This library in turn invokes synchronous XMLHttpRequest. I can't modify the XPath library, I have to use it as is. There are places where I call XPath from within an Ajax success event. In this case, I get no warning - all good so far. There are places where I call XPath NOT within an Ajax response event. In these cases, I get the warning.

Some answerers have suggested that I just dont call synchronous XMLHttpRequest. This is not a viable solution, as I don't control the  Saxon-JS library. All I can control is the context from which I call the  Saxon-JS library.

Comment: *"If I call the jquery method $.get() the OnSuccess event is run on the non-main thread"* - If you're not using web workers then JS all runs in one thread. *"There are some javascript calls that cause an ugly warning"* - Other than synchronous Ajax, what could cause the ugly warning?

Comment: The only way to make code run on anything other than the main thread is to use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). However, it sounds like you should just not use synchronous Ajax.

Comment: I love how the **"what I have tried so far"** includes an imaginary function that solves the problem xD

Comment: @nnnnnn The Saxon-js library (www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documetation/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon-JS will only use synchronous calls on XMLHttpRequest if your XSLT stylesheet (or a dynamically-evaluated XPath expression) makes calls on functions such as doc() or document(). Saxon-JS provides alternatives to these constructs, by using the ixsl:schedule-action instruction to make an asynchronous request. Unfortunately, the fact that you aren't using the functions that trigger a synchronous request doesn't prevent the browser issuing this warning. I don't know any way to prevent the warning, but you should be able to safely ignore it.

PS: Just been discussing this with my colleagues. There may still be some cases where Saxon-JS makes synchronous requests for other resources, such as the Unicode character tables used for evaluating some regular expressions. We will investigate further. Please raise an issue on the Saxon-JS project at saxonica.plan.io so we can track this to a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

> To this end, how can I test if the current thread is the main thread or a non-main thread?

Unless you are explicitly using web workers, you can (and should) assume that your code is always running in the main thread.

Don't use synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`s.

Comment: Not a viable solution in my situation. Refer to update 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a synchronous test for the main thread in Node.js or Web browsers...

```
export const bNode = (typeof process !== 'undefined') && (process.release.name === 'node');

function isMainThread() {
    if (bNode) {
        let bNodeWorker = false;
        let args = process.argv;
        let arWorkerJs = [ // List of all files used with Worker constructor
            "NodeWorker.js"
        ];
        for (let arg of args) {
            for (let wjs of arWorkerJs)
                if (arg.endsWith("/" + wjs))
                    bNodeWorker = true;
        }
        return !bNodeWorker;
    } else {
        // Easy test for Web browsers...
        return self === self.window;
    }
}
export const bMainThread = isMainThread();
```

Please note that the above code is *synchronous*, so it can be used to help setup global scope const-s and variables.

In node-only JS source you can just use `import {isMainThread} from "node:worker_threads";` but this won't load in Web browsers.  If you try to dynamically import `node:worker_threads` in Web browsers then you need to use a promise, which will only resolve *after* your global variables were setup.

In my case I used "bMainThread" from above to setup worker threads with JS source code shared between Node.js (with ES modules) or Web browsers.  For example....

```
if (bMainThread) {
    setupWorkerThreads();
    setupMainThreadMessageHandling();
    useWorkerThreads();
} else {
    setupWorkerMessageHandling();
}
```